# How to track two dimentional array data using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angularjs. I learned some basic concepts and I started developing a form. According to my requirements, I have to give 4 textboxes and if user wants wants more he adds another 4 textboxes. Meanwhile, I am unable to track the entered details.

```js
// create angular app
  var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp','');

  // create angular controller
  validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
      var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
      $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
    };
    $scope.showChoiceLabel = function (choice) {
      return choice.id === $scope.choices[0].id;
    };
    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      if($scope.choices.length>1){
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length-1;
        $scope.choices.pop();
      }

    };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">  
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Family Details</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="id.family_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Family Memeber Name" size="20">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.relation" name="id.family_relation" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Relation" size="15">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.age" name="id.family_age" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Age" size="5">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.qualification" name="id.family_qualification" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Qualification" size="15">
            <br/><button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()" class="btn btn-success">Add another member</button>
            <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" class="btn btn-danger">Remove field</button>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "track array data"? The code seems okay to me.

Comment: if i added 4 members data it showing only last entered data. i want to keep all data in choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have had an error in your initialisation of your app. The empty array in `angular.module('validationApp', [])`. This array is the list of modules myApp depends on:

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp',[]);
```

Further information in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

```js
// create angular app
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

  // create angular controller
  validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];

    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
      var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
      $scope.choices.push({id:'choice' + newItemNo});
    };

    $scope.showChoiceLabel = function(choice) {
      return choice.id === $scope.choices[0].id;
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
      if($scope.choices.length > 1) {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        $scope.choices.pop();
      }

    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController"> 
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Family Details</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="id.family_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Family Memeber Name" size="20">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.relation" name="id.family_relation" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Relation" size="15">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.age" name="id.family_age" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Age" size="5">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.qualification" name="id.family_qualification" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Qualification" size="15">
            <br/><button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()" class="btn btn-success">Add another member</button>
            <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" class="btn btn-danger">Remove field</button>
        </div>
  </div>
```